# How do I know the Hexadecimal to use to communicate with my serial port?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

Background information: I am using Visual Studio 2005 to write MFC/C++ on a dialog box. Please pardon me if I lack out any information or anything essential to answer my question. I will be checking this everyday from 9am - 5:30pm, so please don't hesitate to ask for any more background information.

I do know how to Open, Read, Write and Close a serial port using MFC/C++. The problem is I do not know what to send to the serial port. I have seen my colleagues sending Hexadecimal as such:

> 21 04 07 00 08 00 0F 22

My job is to display signal, noise and threshold onto the following graphs from the rx and tx board. The rx and tx boards are located at the bottom of things as such: (ttp://www.joyfay.com/images/fei833/POSsystem/SSS05.jpg)

1. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2qdbnf8&s=8#.U_7vU_mSxnQ
2. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29vxzmg&s=8#.U_7vi_mSxnQ

I am ready to learn and I am not asking for direct answers. I hope my fellow programming seniors in Stack Overflow can help me out here. Many thanks.

Comment: this isn't really a C++ question, it's a question about how to drive a serial port which is off-topic for here

Comment: You'll need to consult the device's API documentation.

Comment: I have been searching online and I have seen most people asking about how to Open, Read, Write and Close port. When it comes to writing port, they always seem to know what to write in Hexadecimal already and just lack the knowledge of the code for Open, Read, Write and Close port. I am the other way around. Any ideas on where I should look to? Much appreciated.

Comment: Is the device API documentation a manual guide? Or should I look into the firmware?

Comment: @BryanSeTo, either or both. If you have the firmware, then that would work. Else ask the manufacturer. If your company is the manufacturer, then ask some of your co-workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to dig up the documentation for the device you are talking to.  It should provide you with the protocol that's used to exchange data.  Ask your colleagues about it, they surely know where that documentation is located.

I can only make rough guesses from

> 21 04 07 00 08 00 0F 22

The 0x21 byte is likely to be the start byte that indicates the start of the frame.  The device uses it to synchronize itself in order to detect the start of a frame.  The 0x22 byte is likely to be the end byte, a confirmation that no more bytes are expected to follow.  The device uses it to know that the frame was received in full so it can process the data.  The 0x04 byte is likely to be a length byte, it encodes how many data bytes follow.  Which appear to be 0x07, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00.  Pretty unguessable what they encode, it might be two 16-bit values for example, 7 and 8.  The 0x0f byte is probably the checksum of the data bytes, used to verify that the data bytes were not corrupted.

Very rough guesses, read the documentation to know for sure.  And of course talk to your colleagues about it, little point in asking a completely stranger on the Internet when you have people that know the facts in the cubicle next to yours.  Petzold's book "Code" is pretty good to help you stop talking about "hex".

Comment: I am starting to understand a bit more what this set of hexadecimal is trying to say. Yup, I will heed the advice and ask my colleagues about it. Thanks for the explanation, tips and resource regarding this matter.

Comment: I have consulted my supervisor regarding this matter who has written a similar software. He said that the previous person who coded this software did not leave any protocol or documentation behind and it was badly done. I would like to ask if it's possible to look at the firmware and try to understand this line of Hexadecimal. Or should I devise my own protocol?