# How to read HEX values from Serial Port using VB.Net 2015

Tags: vb.net

I tied to get serial values using VB.Net. Also, I am using third party software to check whrether data sending/receiving or not.

When I Send `01 03 0B D3 00 0A 36 10` HEX data, I should get `01 03 14 43 5E 7E A7 FF C0 00 00 FF C0 00 00 FF FF FF FF 43 5E 7E A7 DE F7` data. This data length and values can be changed according to send data.

Data sending code is perfectly working.

First I tried using the following code,

```
Dim gg As String = MyCOMPort.ReadExisting()
ListBox1.Items.Add(gg)
```

I did not get any data to Listbox also third party software only show send data.

Secondly, I tried the following code,

```
Dim bufferArr(MyCOMPort.ReadBufferSize) As Byte
Dim Incoming As Integer = MyCOMPort.Read(bufferArr, 0, bufferArr.Length)
ListBox1.Items.Add(Incoming)
```

Then I get only 1 which is the first HEX value. Third-party software also shows 01 data on the receiving side.

Thirdly I used following code,

```
Dim aa As String = MyCOMPort.ReadLine
ListBox1.Items.Add(aa)
```

Then my programme is getting a stack and not getting any data but Third-party software shows all `01 03 14 43 5E 7E A7 FF C0 00 00 FF C0 00 00 FF FF FF FF 43 5E 7E A7 DE F7` data which is I want to get.

How to get HEX serial data properly? Why I can not get all data?

First, of code have the following codes,

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Ports
```

I am getting all serial data by code without using SerialPort tool.

Comment: The byte values in the response are not arbitrary, they are designed to help you read the response correctly.  01 helps you synchronize and recognize the start of the response.  14 is the length byte, helps you to figure out when you stop calling Read().  There is probably a checksum at the end of the message.  An example of such a protocol is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25545974/17034  If you don't have a good manual that describes this protocol then ask the vendor/manufacturer for one.  They can also provide you with sample code that shows how to do it right, you need it.

Comment: @HansPassant : I'm not very familiar with the technology. Does all (or most) serial port devices work like this? (start/synchronize byte, etc.) I haven't seen many other questions/answers adapt to this format.

Comment: It is fairly common.  Much more so in industrial devices, serial ports have no decent error detection and correction mechanism, Parity doesn't cut it.  Serial ports sit at the bottom of the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), layer 1.  A protocol like this implements layer 2.

Comment: @HansPassant : Interesting... Thanks for the info!